# Obtener Historial de MS-Edge con c#

Tags: c#

He estado buscando como obtener el historial de MS-Edge por medio de una aplicación de consola con c# pero no he tenido la misma suerte que con explorer utilizando `Interop.SHDocVw`, quisiera saber si es posible leerlo con alguna librería externa o algo por el estilo, O almenos obtener el url y el titulo de las pestañas abiertas actualmente.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Siempre se pide que digas que investigaste hasta ahora o que probaste y no sirvio.

Comment: algunas pistas aqui https://stackoverflow.com/q/49747766/1423096